# laravel define relation over multiple tables

Tags: laravel

I have a table `customers` with the fields `id`, `name` and so on.

One table `doctors` with the fields `id`, `name`.

Then there is one table `subject_areas` which has all subject areas which a doctor can have. The fields are `id`, `text`.

So, each doctor can have multiple subject areas. There is one pivot table `doctor_subject` which is a belongsToMany relation.

Here is my problem: A customer can have multiple doctors, but only for a specific subject area. I tried it with a new table `customer_doctor` with the fields `id`, `customer_id` and `doctor_subject_id`. But how do i map this in Eloquent?

Comment: can doctors and customers sign in into your app?

Comment: yes, i have already a  `users` table/model where customers and doctors extend from.

Comment: ok, so you are saving all of them into users table? Both doctors and customers?

Comment: yes for e.g. username, password and so. Other informations are going into the customers and doctors table. The User Model has relations to customers and doctors via `type` field in the users table.

Comment: OK so, a doctor can have multiple customers and a customer can belong to many doctors, there you need a pivot table customer_doctor

Comment: yep, but a doctor can have multiple subject areas, and the customer belongs to many subject areas of a doctor (and can have multiple doctors)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159668/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-nutzt).

Comment: Can you open the chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was in relation between tables. After chat clarification this came out as solution:

[image]

Html form is written in a way that customer first choose doctor, then depending on selection choose several of his available areas. 
In that scenario customer needn't to be related to areas directly and should be related to areas only over relation with doctor. 
Also as side note, if needed deeper relations, models on pivot tables could be created and used as well.

Comment: You could remove doctor_customer_doctor_id and doctor_customer_customer_id from area_doctor_customer. It's already available through the relationships. Glad you've figured it out.

Comment: When I put n:m table onto MySQL Workbench diagram it created schema with all composite keys this way automatically. It doesn't hurt but you are right. Thanks.